# Can't open links from Intellij: "Error KIO Client: Unable to create io-slave. Can not create socket for launching io-slave for protocol 'https'."

Tags: kde, snap, intellij

Since I switched to the snap version (`--classic`) of Intellij I can't open any external link (to web sites) from this app. Whenever I click a link I receive the following error:

> Error - KIO Client
>
> Unable to create io-slave. Can not create socket for launching io-slave for protocol 'https'.

Versions:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- KDE Frameworks 5.44.0
- Qt 5.9.5 (built against 5.9.5)
- snap    2.37.1.1+18.04
- snapd   2.37.1.1+18.04
- series  16
- Ubuntu  18.04
- Kernel  4.15.0-45-generic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not familiar with "KIO Client" and what it is.

But for myself, I needed to force the default Web Browser in KDE. Specifically I followed these steps.

1. Open **System Settings**
2. Under the **Personalization** section in the left menu, choose **Applications** then **Default Applications**.
3. In the list of Default Applications, choose **Web Browser**
4. From the **Default Component** section select **In the Following Application** and choose your preferred browser from the list.
5. Click the **Apply** button.

---

For myself, my default component for the web browser was set to **In an Application Based on the Contents of the URL** -- which seems ideal, but then it doesn't see to resolve HTTPS to any application. I suspect changing this may have other unintended side effects.

Comment: I had a similar problem where file links were failing when using Dolphin.  To resolve it I followed Courtney's instructions but instead of web browser I chose file manager > Other and clicked Add to manually add in a path to Dolphin the path I used was  'dolphin %u'.  This worked a treat.

Comment: Courtney's solution also helped with vscode setting sync via github.

Comment: This answer also helped resolve a problem with a Lord Of The Rings Online "Open Store in External Browser" failure.  It was giving a KIO Client SSL Negotiation Error, which is slightly different than the error in the question, but similar enough that it showed up in searches.