# Snap apps broken with Ubuntu, KDE Wayland, and ZSH

Tags: kubuntu, snap, zsh

#### Issues I had

- Icons when launching via `snap run <appname>` were the default X icon, not the ones provided by snap
- Trying to get OAuth working with things like Todoist (Google SSO in browser, redirect back to app) were broken, giving me an error about KIO Client not understanding the protocol.
- Trying to use `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh'` did not work in my `~/.zshrc`
- I was unwilling to use `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'`
- Adding `snap` to the bin path *did not work* in resolving anything
- KRunner could not find snap-installed apps
- Any launcher installed could not find snap-installed apps
- Manually adding launchers to Latte Dock was buggy

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so no solutions actually worked for me. I had *everything* everyone else stated (adding to /etc/environment, the emulate command, everything).

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 with ZSH. My solution is to synchronize your local applications folder with the snap folder.

#### As a script

Add this file to any folder that is part of your "bin" path. For me, I have `~/.local/bin`, but you may have something else. **Make sure** what ever directory you use [is part of your path variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path). I added this file as `~/.local/bin/sync-snap-apps` to my system.

```
#! /bin/zsh

shareApps="$HOME/.local/share/applications"
snapApps="/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications"

# Detect all installed applications by snap
for file in $snapApps/*.desktop
do
  # Get a not-ugly version of the .desktop 
  # Example: todoist_todoist.desktop -> todoist.desktop
  link="$shareApps/$(echo $file | cut -d '_' -f2)"

  # Create new link if none exists
  [[ -f $link ]] || ln -s $file $link
done


# NOTE: Remove this if you do NOT want automatic broken symbolic link cleanup
for link in $shareApps/*.desktop; do
  # Remove any broken *.desktop symbolic links
  [[ -e $link ]] || rm $link
done
```

Now that this file is added to your system, append `sync-snap-apps` to the end of your `~/.zshrc` and start up a new terminal. It will automatically sync up your snap applications.

### As a zshrc addition

Put this at the bottom of your `~/.zshrc` file

```
shareApps="$HOME/.local/share/applications"
snapApps="/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications"

# Detect all installed applications by snap
for file in $snapApps/*.desktop
do
  # Get a not-ugly version of the .desktop 
  # Example: todoist_todoist.desktop -> todoist.desktop
  link="$shareApps/$(echo $file | cut -d '_' -f2)"

  # Create new link if none exists
  [[ -f $link ]] || ln -s $file $link
done


# NOTE: Remove this if you do NOT want automatic broken symbolic link cleanup
for link in $shareApps/*.desktop; do
  # Remove any broken *.desktop symbolic links
  [[ -e $link ]] || rm $link
done
```

---

### Final Notes

Note, this solved the following issues for me:

1. [Error KIO Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116344/cant-open-links-from-intellij-error-kio-client-unable-to-create-io-slave-ca), I could not use Google Auth redirects to Snap applications, similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116344/cant-open-links-from-intellij-error-kio-client-unable-to-create-io-slave-ca) and [this github issue](https://github.com/Figma-Linux/figma-linux/issues/130).
2. Apps are not in launcher, similar to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9pjos2/snaps_in_application_launcher/) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989871/i-cant-use-snap-packages-even-if-installed).  Related to [this forum post](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-application-launchers-dont-appear-in-applications-menu-when-using-zsh-how-i-fixed-it/22334) on SnapCraft.

The solution came from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051397/1185319), and is easier to understand than [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060075/1185319) on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the mentioned `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh'` to `/etc/zsh/zprofile` did the trick. (I am working with KUbuntu 23.10, zsh v5.9) This was replicated by someone else I suggested this to.